# BizTalk Business Activity Monitor

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-bam

I recently started with the BAM from BizTalk.

- I created a simple orchestration.
- I configured the BAM for BizTalk ofcourse.
- I used excel to create a simple schema with only textfields.
- I deployed this xml schema to the BizTalk primary import using: bm deploy-all -DefinitionFile:myxml.xml.
- Opened the TPE and opened the deployed schema.
- Opened the orchestration and here opened the used schema and linked the schemafields to the bamschemafields.
- After this I applied the tracking profile.
- I then put a file through BizTalk which uses the orchestration. The file was outputted.

If I now check in the primary import database, I can see that the file is visible in the active messages. But the completed field is set to false. And it doesn't change. Also no data is filled in, only the ActivityID and LastModified, none of the columns which i specified myself are filled, and also RecordID = null.

What am I doing wrong?

I thought I did all the necessary steps, I know it's all still pretty basic but I need to get this to work if I want to do more, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Getting BAM to work can be tricky sometimes. First, did you restart your biztalk hosts after deploying everything? That could cause issues if you didn't.

Almost the first thing I do when I run into any issues with BAM is to turn on [BAM tracing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb203854(BTS.20).aspx) and either redirect it to a file or use [DbgView](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896647.aspx) to check for any errors BAM might be running into.

One of the crappy things about BAM is that it will fail silently sometimes, with the only information about the error being dump on the BAM tracing, so getting familiar with it is important.

Comment: Well, I turned on tracking for the bam manager and tracking for the event bus.

The manager log was never made, is this normal? Because I would think the problem would lie in here.

The event bus log was created but showed very few info.

Comment: The manager log is for when you run bm.exe, so that's no use here. For the event bus log settings, did you set the Microsoft.BizTalk.Bam.EventBus switch to 4? (full debug info)

Comment: It was on 1, I changed it to 4. Don't see anything new now tho :( Only stuff like:

ExecuteReader Info Thread 0 Reads 1 Records 
ExecuteBatch Info Thread 0 completes batch execution of records 
ExecuteBatch Info Thread 0 completes batch execution of records 
CleanupReader Info Thread 0 deletes Processed Records from Source Database 
ExecuteReader Info Thread 0 Reads 1 Records 
ExecuteBatch Info Thread 0 completes batch execution of records 
TimeoutMonitor Info Sleeping for Session timeout period 
CleanupReader Info Thread 0 deletes Processed Records from Source Database

Comment: Don't know if this is relevant, but my orchestration uses an atomic scope.

Comment: It could be that your TPE profile is just wrong... how did you associate the message fields to the observation model?

Comment: I used Message Payload Schema's on my receive shape of my orchestration and link these to my observation model.

Comment: It works! I have no idea why. I read that there were problems when using the receive shape, so I tested it on the send shape and it worked. Then I found that a couple of messages were already also in the database and I retried it on the receive shape and it also works. I can't seem to remember I modified anything except for some log files and the bam portal configuration which has nothing to do with it... Well, it works so! :) Thanks for your help